# maven spring boot returns 'Unable to start embedded Tomcat' error

Tags: maven, tomcat

When I run “mvn spring-boot:run” I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

I'm not sure what's causing it... my pom.xml file is too long to post here but I wonder if this is the issue and I should comment out the exclusions:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why have you added the exclusion?

Comment: There is no server to start it since it got excluded in the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. Need to remove the `exclusions` and run it again.

Comment: I didn't create the pom file, a contractor who converted a python program to a web app did it, so I'm a little out of my depth here. I see <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> in actually 3 places, only one of which is an exclusion. Not sure why...